# How to use an Object as a map key instead of String for MongoDB Java

Tags: java, mongodb, serialization, pojo, bson

Based on the way MongoDB's Java Driver handles POJOs, Maps must always have a key of type String. I understand you can use Codecs to have it handle lots of data types of your own, but I can't figure out if there's a way you can register a codec so that you can serialize/deserialize a Map.

Is this possible? Presently I'm having to make all my classes Map and then do JIT streams to conform the data, but I feel like this is possible and I just can't quite figure it out. Thanks!